# Using data from csv in nvd3 graph

Tags: html, csv, nvd3.js

I'm using my Ubuntu server to run automated speed tests and am recording the data in a csv file. I'd like to now plot all this data in a graph. The `csv` file is called data.csv in the same directory as index.html and it contains the following:

```
time,ping,down,up
1454190169992.8655,25.40,61.1,18.2
1454196940589.804,24.57,65.8,18.2
1454200093536.6118,26.39,66.8,18.2
1454235805528.2244,25.21,59.3,18.1
1454235966417.7297,25.01,59.4,18.2
1454236051628.0317,24.68,59.8,18.2
1454239827546.229,26.63,64.6,18.2
```

**index.html** currently looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="nv.d3.css" />
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="nv.d3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <svg id="chart" style="width:500; height:500;"></svg>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data){
            console.log(data)
            // create an empty object that nv is expecting
        var exampleData = [
            {
                key: "totals",
                values: []
            }
        ];

            // populate the empty object with your data
        data.forEach(function (d){
            d.value = +d.value
            exampleData[0].values.push(d)
        })   

    nv.addGraph(function() {
        var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
            .margin({left: 100})  //Adjust chart margins to give the x-axis some breathing room.
            .useInteractiveGuideline(true)  //We want nice looking tooltips and a guideline!
            .transitionDuration(350)  //how fast do you want the lines to transition?
            .showLegend(true)       //Show the legend, allowing users to turn on/off line series.
            .showYAxis(true)        //Show the y-axis
            .showXAxis(true)        //Show the x-axis
            .x(function (d) { console.log(d); return d.time })
            .y(function (d) { return d.ping })

        d3.select('#chart')
            .datum(exampleData)
            .attr("id", function (d) { console.log(d); })
          .transition().duration(500)
              .call(chart);


        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
        return chart;
   });
});
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you have any console error?

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: Open your html page with chart and press f12. Reload page and check console field.

Comment: Thank you for your help but I've successfully solved the problem by using amcharts instead